# Dynamics 365 - IOrganizationService/Web Api

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-365

With CRM Dynamics 365 being released, Microsoft have officially deprecated the 2011 soap end point and are actively pushing their Web Api.

[Deprecated Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn281891.aspx)

What I would like to know though is how this affects my connections to CRM.

Currently I use the Tooling library to create instances of OrganizationServiceProxy using the CrmServiceClient class and a connection string. Would this have to change as I have many hundred of thousands of lines of code that all reference IOrganizationService.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm more worried about scripts: since it's deprecated, it's likely that in the next major release (I'd guess around 2018) we'll lose OrganizationData.svc and the ability to issue FetchXML queries. Upgrading 2011 envs will be *lovely* then

Comment: @Alex, I don't see anything mentioned about `FetchXml` being deprecated on any of the official docs. If plans on deprecating `FetchXml` is true, it is going to be a big thing. Any link to where it is documented? Or is just news from the developer conferences?

Comment: I have no source, it's only a worry I have, since here https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn281891.aspx it's written "You must update existing applications to use the Dynamics 365 Web API for accessing Dynamics 365 web services between now and the removal of the 2011 endpoint"

Comment: @Alex You can still make FetchXml calls using the Web Api
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607533.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, that will be a transparent update and you should only have to upgrade to the latest package versions and [rebuild your projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn281891.aspx#bkmk_assemblyUpdates), in theory. :)

Comment: I've heard this reiterated at both ExtremeCrm 2015, and another conference this year as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is some C# and not JavaScript using that 2011 endpoint. Microsoft deprecated the `Xrm.Client` in favor of the `Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector`.

You can replace your connection with `Xrm.Tooling.Connector` and generally your code will work

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602970.aspx

Answer (score 0):

CrmServiceClient class will work, I am using this class for all my WCF integration services with Dynamics 365. This depreciation is mainly going to affect scripts that uses old REST and SOAP calls.

As a good practice, you can always use libraries from latest SDK and rebuild the projects to ensure that your codes are updated.